# Increasing a digit end of string value

Tags: c, for-loop

I want to increase a value end of string with for loop in C.
You will see 2 for loop i actually wanted to increase i and x value simultaneously. I am new in C I moved from python and I am also open to your advice about C.

P.S: DL_ numbers actually is not static I increment them with external button so I should get their value dynamically

For example :

```
uint8_t DL_1=7;
uint8_t DL_2=4;
uint8_t DL_3=2;
uint8_t DL_4=1;


for(int i=0;i<=180;i+=16) {
    for(int x=1;i<=4;i++) {
        printf(i,DL_x)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to have a look at `man printf`.

Comment: I am not able to give vote up due to low rep score and I cant mark as a accepted 2 answers. I’d like to give those 2 answers because they replied so I wanted to show my appreciate about their labor , writing “thank you”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> for(int i=0;i<=180;i+=16) {
>     for(int x=1;i<=4;i++) {
>         printf(i,DL_x)
>     }
> }
> ```

You're increasing `i` twice.
Maybe the second loop should use `x` everywhere: `for(int x = 1; x <= 4; x++)`.
To print two integers separated by a space and terminated with a newline, `printf()` should be used as `printf("%d %d\n", i, DL_1);`
Consider using an array (and **remember array indexes go from `0` to `n - 1`**) rather than 4 separate variables

```
int DL[4] = {7, 4, 2, 1};
printf("%d\n", DL[1]); // prints 4
```

Comment: Thank you , I wrote with my hand  and I forgot to replace x instead of i. Thanx again array method should be solve my problem. I guess there is no possiblity with DL_x C is not understant this declaration.

Answer (score 0):

To increment x and i simultaneously, you can use just a single loop with comma separated statements:

```
for(int i = 0, x = 1; i <= 180 ; i += 16, x++)
{
    printf(i,DL_x);
}
```

But there are other problems with your code, so it still will not compile, which I hope you understand.

Comment: Thank you I will handle other problems using array